# Chain functions after OK/unwrap/expect

Tags: rust

In Rust, is it possible to chain more functions after ok, unwrap or expect?

Given code:

```rust
stdin()
    .read_line(&mut guess)
    .ok()
    .expect("Couldn't read line!");
```

If I want to `trim` the string, is there a syntax like this?

```rust
stdin()
    .read_line(&mut guess)
    .ok().trim()
    .expect("Couldn't read line!");
```

I know using match I could do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264723/15504324

Comment: `.ok().expect()`? `.expect()` alone is enough.

Comment: You need to `.expect().trim()`, not the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In this case the problem is that, you cannot, because the buffer is `guess`, readline would return the bytes read**

Anyway:

You can use `map` to operate the value in case there is any **Before** unwraping/expecting:

```rust
Ok("Foo bar ")
    .ok()
    .map(str::trim)
    .expect("Couldn't read line!");
```

**After** it you can use the type already, so just chain the call.

```rust
Ok("Foo bar ")
    .unwrap()
    .trim();
```

Comment: They're `expect()`ing, so pretty much not needed.